# How to pass a list with one empty element in cmake?

Tags: list, cmake, representation

I have a cmake function which expects a list as one of its arguments. In cmake, a list is represented by a string with the list elements separated by semicola. I can pass an empty list as `""`, a list of one element as `"foo"`, and a list of multiple elements as, e.g., `"foo1;foo2;foo3"`. Even passing a list of two empty elements as `";"` works as expected. But how do I pass a list with one single empty element?

I googled around a bit and found this post:

http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake-developers/2013-July/007738.html

which covers a similar issue, but I couldn't find any follow-ups.

So, is it even possible to pass a list with exactly one empty element, and if so, how?

Comment: Empty list and list with one empty element has identical representation. You need to find a use case specific solution if you want to distinguish the two. What is your use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add extra argument that represents the name of parameter. This is widely used pattern in CMake:

```
# usage: foo(FOO arg0 arg1 arg2 ...)

function(foo)
  list(LENGTH ARGV x)
  # check first is FOO here
  math(EXPR argn "${x} - 1")

  if(argn EQUAL 0)
    message("argn: 0 |")
    return()
  endif()

  set(output)
  foreach(index RANGE 1 ${argn})
    list(GET ARGV ${index} current)
    set(output "${output} `${current}`")
  endforeach()

  message("argn: ${argn} | argv:${output}")
endfunction()

foo(FOO)
foo(FOO "")
foo(FOO "1")
foo(FOO "1" "")
foo(FOO "1" "abc")
```

Result:

```
argn: 0 |
argn: 1 | argv: ``
argn: 1 | argv: `1`
argn: 2 | argv: `1` ``
argn: 2 | argv: `1` `abc`
```

As you can see there is a case with zero arguments and case with one empty argument.

Comment: And you might want to use the [ParseArguments module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/CMakeParseArguments.html) to save you from having to manually parse argument strings.

Comment: This is a useful pattern, but it doesn't work in cases where multiple lists are passed to a function. In my case however, only one of the parameters must be able to accept a list of one empty element as argument, so I can make that work by using your pattern on that parameter only. Therefore, accepted.

Comment: @ruslo you're correct. Sorry, I misunderstood the significance of FOO.